# Firebase work in background

Tags: android, firebase, уведомления, background

Подключил firebase, а именно messaging. Если приложение открыто или свёрнуто, то уведомления приходят. А если выгрузить его то нет. и ничего не помгает.

При этом в логах вот это:

```
05-02 21:41:57.035 1166-1203/system_process E/ActivityManager: isAutoRunBlockedApp:: by.nikita_dol.celby, Auto Run OFF
05-02 21:41:57.035 1166-1203/system_process V/AutoRunDefaultOff:  action=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE, callerPkg=com.google.android.gms, calleePkg=by.nikita_dol.celby
05-02 21:41:57.035 1166-1203/system_process V/AutoRunDefaultOff:  This is target model of AutoRun :by.nikita_dol.celby
05-02 21:41:57.035 1166-1203/system_process E/ActivityManager: isAutoRunBlockedApp:: by.nikita_dol.celby, Auto Run OFF
05-02 21:41:57.035 1166-1203/system_process V/AutoRunDefaultOff:  action=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE, callerPkg=com.google.android.gms, calleePkg=by.nikita_dol.celby
05-02 21:41:57.035 1166-1203/system_process V/AutoRunDefaultOff:  This is target model of AutoRun :by.nikita_dol.celby
05-02 21:41:57.035 1665-1665/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GCM-DMM: broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000000 pkg=by.nikita_dol.celby (has extras) }
```

В AndroidManifest есть это:

```
<permission
    android:name="by.nikita_dol.celby.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="by.nikita_dol.celby.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

и это

```
<service
        android:name=".data.PushService"
        android:exported="false">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".data.InstanceIdService"
        android:exported="false">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </service>

    <receiver android:name="by.nikita_dol.celby.PushBroadCast" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <category android:name="by.nikita_dol.celby"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Как принимать уведомления?

Answer (score 0):

Официальная документация гласит следующее:

[Ссылка](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

**Handle notification messages in a backgrounded app**

When your app is in the background, Android directs notification messages to the system tray. A user tap on the notification opens the app launcher by default.

This includes messages that contain both notification and data payload (and all messages sent from the Notifications console). In these cases, the notification is delivered to the device's system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

Тоесть, firebase автоматически создаёт Notification, если твоё приложение находится в бекграунде! **НО** для автоматического создания Notification следует указать в манифесте:

[Ссылка](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />

<meta-data
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Первое - иконка по умолчанию, второе - цвет по умолчанию!

Comment: Не приходят всё равно.